What is the yellow bubble surrounding brawlers?
It's kind of embarrassing that I've been playing Brawl Stars for a long time but still haven't figured out what the yellow bubble is that I see some brawlers sport from time to time. I Googled a fair bit but I have only been able to find posts like these ones without much of an explanation (link, link). The bubble I see seems to be the "normal shield" in these posts, but I can't seem to find a corresponding gadget or gear in these brawlers' profiles. Fang players always seem to be able to invoke the bubble whenever they want. I recently encountered a Bibi with a yellow bubble at the start of the battle, which I have never seen before.

I don't think it's the same shield each time. From what I saw in the second link, there were multiple brawlers with different yellow shields and shield descriptions, so I'd assume it's one of their gadgets. Also, according to the Fang Fandom subsection, the yellow shield is, "His second Star Power, Divine Soles, periodically grants Fang a special shield that partially reduces damage from the next enemy attack"

The yellow bubble surrounding some brawlers is a percentage based shield and is almost always through star powers. The shield means that a certain percentage of damage is reduced (but the exact amount differs by the brawler)
The second reddit post is outdated (3 years old is a lot) meaning some of the things you are looking for might not exist.
